# What is the usefulness of project1st<Arg1, Arg2> in the STL?

Tags: c++, stl, functional-programming

I was browsing the SGI STL documentation and ran into [`project1st<Arg1, Arg2>`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/project1st.html). I understand its definition, but I am having a hard time imagining a practical usage.

Have you ever used project1st or can you imagine a scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that if you were using the strategy pattern and had a situation where you needed to pass an identity object, this would be a good choice.  For example, there might be a case where an algorithm takes several such objects, and perhaps it is possible that you want one of them to do nothing under some situation.

Comment: Quite: it has a roughly equivalent purpose to passing 0 as the size parameter of std::copy_n. It saves the user having to propagate a special case throughout their code. They can just specify an identify functor in one place, then treat it like any other functor.

Answer (score 3):

A variant of project1st (taking a `std::pair`, and returning `.first`) is quite useful. You can use it in combination with `std::transform` to copy the keys from a `std::map<K,V>` to a `std::vector<K>`. Similarly, a variant of `project2nd` can be used to copy the values from a map to a `vector<V>`.

As it happens, none of the standard algorithms really benefits from project1st. The closest is partial_sum(project1st), which would set all output elements to the first input element. It mainly exists because the STL is heavily founded in mathematical set theory, and there operations like project1st are basic building blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel programming. Imagine a situation where two processes come up with two valid but different results for a given computation, and you need to force them to be the same. project1st/2nd provides a very convenient way to perform this operation on a whole container, using an appropriate parallel call that takes a functor as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that *someone* had a practical use for it, or it wouldn't have been written, but I'm drawing a blank on what it might have been. Presumably its use-case is similar to the `identity` function that the description mentions, where there's no real need for processing but the syntax requires a functor anyway.

The example on that same page suggests using it with the two-container form of `std::transform`, but if I'm not mistaken, the way they're using it is functionally identical to `std::copy`, so I don't see the point.

It looks like a solution in search of a problem to me.